# Google Sheets - Filter views on Mobile

Tags: android, windows, mobile, google-sheets, tablet

I created filter views in google sheets for real time data. In my office they are saying not to use google sheets on office computer so I wanted to use these filter views on my Mobile (Android) but I see there is no filter views option available in google sheets. Could anyone please advise what is the other option so that filter views can be used on Mobile device?

Comment: Have you read [Sort & filter your data (Android)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)?

Comment: Yes but i have complex filters in filter views which I don't or can't create everytime in realtime, that is not good for my work.

Comment: I do appreciate the problem, but that reference makes it very clear "Note: Filter views are only available on a computer. " You asked what is the "other option"? Answer: There isn't one. The same applies for IOS [Is there a way to use Google Sheets filter views on IOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283320)

Comment: Is Filter views available on Windows OS Mobile or Tablet?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use desktop browser version of Google Sheets on mobile. (On Chrome for Android, for example, there is a "Desktop site" checkmark in the menu.)

However, at least in Chrome on my phone, requesting the desktop version of the page results in very zoomed out view that can be a hard to use. I sort of got used to it already, zooming in and out with doubletaps all the time, so maybe it would work for you too.

On my 10" tablet, the desktop browser version is perfectly usable, especially in portrait orientation.